# A case where the sum of independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ is independent of $X$.

Tags: probability

If $X,Y$ are independent random variables with values $0,\ldots,n-1$ such that $Z:=(X+Y) \mod n$ and $X$ are independent, show that $Y$ is uniform over ${0,...,n-1}$.

I've been struggling with this question. I've first assumed that $Y$ is not uniform, so there exists $a,b$ such that $P(Y=a)$ and $P(Y=b)$ are different.

I've tried showing that since $X,Z$ are independent, $P(Z=r|X=r-a) = P(Z=r) = P(Z=r|X=r-b)$ implies $P(Y=a)=P(Y=b)$ and get a contradiction but I'm not sure if the last equality is true.

Comment: Compute $P[X=x;Z=z]$ using two different ways.

Comment: By ";" you mean intersection of events or conditional probability? And I can only think of one way using the independency of $X,Z$. Is there a way to get $Y$ involved?

Comment: Independence. The event $[X=x;Z=z]$ is the same as $[X=x;Y=(z-x)\mod n]$. Note that I completed the assumptions by adding that $X$ and $Y$ takes values in $0,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! And I'm sorry but I still don't completely understand -- since $X,Z$ are independent we get $P[X=x;Z=z] = P[X=x]P[Z=z]$ on on hand, and by your suggestion on the other hand $P[X=x]P[Y=(z-x)$ mod $n]$. So We get $P[Z=z]=P[Y=(z-x)$ mod $n]$? Or is that not the conclusion you were aiming for?

Comment: You have to add an assumption like $P[X=x]>0$ for all $x \in \{0,...,n-1\}$. Otherwise you cannot divide by $P[X=x]$ and the conclusion may be false (for example when $X=0$ almost surely). Then you have a probability which is a function of $z$ only, but also a function of $(z-x) \mod p$ only. Since $x$ varies in $\{0,...,n-1\}$ it must be constant. Here we use that addition modulo $n$ provides a group structure: for every $y$ in $\{0,...,n-1\}$, there is an $x$ in $\{0,...,n-1\}$ such that $z-x=y$.